# Excel formula to get all values in one cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to copy all cells with values into one cell from a specific column, with everytime a CHAR(13) included in between them. This without VBA, just with excel formules.

example:

```
A   |   B
1   | test1
2   | test2
3   | 
4   | test4
```

I want the output in one cell like this:

```
=B1 & CHAR(13) & B2 & CHAR(13) & B4
```

When you add that value as a source to a textbox, you'll get:

```
test1
test2 
test4
```

Anyone have any ideas? This **without** VBA, only via formula's

Comment: This screams [`TEXTJOIN`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,B1:B4)
```

Note the use of *10* rather than *13*.

[image]